# Can’t open /var/../freshclam.log error when updating ClamAV's virus database

Tags: clamav, clamtk

I get this when I  want to update virus data:

```
ERROR: Can’t open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!
```

Any advice to solve this?

Comment: Match the file's ownership and permissions to this: `-rw-r-----  clamav adm  /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log`

Comment: Explore the file's permission with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld